# Excel Formatting Bug - Are There Any Work-Arounds to this?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, cell

I have a very large excel spreadsheet I'm working on that's used by a sales organization, mixed with cells to enter data along with locked text cells to read off of.

Throughout the worksheet, there are sections to where there are 2 font colors in the same merged cell - example would be...

This sentence is black except for just these two **BOLD RED** words.

(Stackoverflow doesn't allow colors...)

I tried using a conditional formatting to have the text the same color as the background to hide the text under some circumstances, but only the first font color in the cell is affected, while the second color remains unchanged from the conditional formatting.

Is there a work-around to this without requiring VBA?

Comment: That's certainly odd behavior that I have never noticed before. It seems that character formatting (e.g. formatting certain letters or words within a phrase) overrides conditional formatting. Even if you used VBA, you would be rewriting the entire phrase either with formatting on certain words or without per the conditions specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the cell's font color with the CF rule. Change the number format to a custom number format of `;;;` (three semi-colons) to hide the text.

[image: cf_hide_text]

The CF rule for A1:A4 is based on the value in B1:B4 with a format of white text. The CF rule in A7:A10 is based on the value in B7:B10 but applies a custom number format of `;;;`. As you can see from the formula bar, the underlying text is still there.